# Is there a way to get the integer value of an enum in visual studio while the program is not running?

Tags: visual-studio, enums

I have several large enums that are used like

```
switch(someEnumValue)
{
  case SomeEnum.Value1:
  DoSomething();
  break;

  case SomeEnum.Value2:
  DoSomethingElse();
  break;

  ...

  case someEnum.ValueBigNumber:
  break;
}
```

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2010 for me to see what the integer value of someEnum.SomeValue is without actually running the program and without manually counting the values in the enum definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built in for this, though you can define the enumerations with the actual integer values directly, so one look at the enum declaration will tell you the members value:

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
   Value1 = 0,
   Value2 = 1,
   ...
   ValueN = 78897
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but will take a lot of work unfortunately.

Comment: Dunno about that - a bit of excel `concatenate` magic can do this in a couple of minutes.

Comment: I have hundreds of these enumerations. I suppose I could write a program to parse / generate new code. But it would be nice if visual studio could just tell me the value.

Comment: @Justin984 - I guess its one of those features that would only be useful to a small percentage of users (and therefore the cost of writing, testing, documenting etc... would be considered not worth it)

Answer (score 2):

Today I was finding a solution for this problem.
I couldn't find a cool solution like visual studio extension.
Instead, I found a useful trick for this problem using template code!

```
template<bool, int> class Value_of_someEnumValue_is;
template<>      class Value_of_someEnumValue_is<false, someEnumValue> {};
Value_of_someEnumValue_is<true, someEnumValue> i;
```

If you compile this code, you will see the integer value of 'someEnumValue' in the error message. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear why you want to do this, but thinking out the box; copy the enum definition into excel and see row number or copy into a new text file in visual studio and check the line number of the cursor (think its bottom right of the ide). Selecting the values from the first may even give you a selected lines count.